# Problema ao utilizar uma variável combo box numérica com casas decimais no GX Ev3 u11

Tags: java, combobox, genexus

Identifiquei um bug ao utilizar uma variável combo box numérica com casas decimais no GX Ev3. Nas versões Ev1 e Ev2 o mesmo exemplo funciona perfeitamente.

Eu não sou bom em escrever, mas vou tentar descrever o problema. Se alguém não entender eu tento de novo!

Quem puder me ajudar faça o seguinte:

1 - Crie uma variável do tipo Numeric(7.2) no WebForm em uma WebPanel.

2 - Na tela defina-a como um combo box com os valores inteiros ou quebrados:

Exemplo:

```
&CASA_DECIMAL.AddItem(100, "100%")
&CASA_DECIMAL.AddItem(75, "75%")
&CASA_DECIMAL.AddItem(50.00, "50%")
&CASA_DECIMAL.AddItem(40.00, "40%")
&CASA_DECIMAL.AddItem(35.15, "35,15%")
```

3 - Crie um evento Enter ou qualquer outro para "printar" o valor da variável de exemplo.

3.1 - Por exemplo, ao selecionar a opção 75% e "printar" o valor através do evento, o valor muda para 7500,00, ao invés de 75,00.

Exemplos:

```
&CASA_DECIMAL.ToFormattedString()  //- O resultado de 75%, é : 7500,00
&CASA_DECIMAL.ToString() // - O resultado de 75%, é: 7500.00.
```

Estou usando GeneXus Ev3(update 11), gerando Java com JDK 1.8.0_101.

Este problema só acontece quando a variável é um combo box. Quando é um input Edit, o valor é printado corretamente.

Comment: Gustavo, se você acha que é um bug, deveria reportar a suporte...

Comment: Reportei Marcos, mas ainda não obtive o feedback. Postarei aqui a solução, caso me respondam. Enquanto não tenho a certeza, gostaria de obter outras opiniões de outros desenvolvedores genexus evo 3. Valeu!

Comment: Qual o número do IT? E quando reportou ao suporte?

Comment: Paulo, eu repassei o problema ontem para gerencia do projeto que participo. Vou solicitar o número da IT, caso já tenha sido reportado. Quando receber eu posto aqui também Paulo. Tem alguma idéia do que pode estar causando o problema?

Comment: Sim, tenho. É um bug que ocorre na ev2, ev2 e v15 quando usa a linguagem dá KB  diferente de inglês. Provavelmente onde funciona está com inglês e onde não funciona está com português. É mais fácil você mesmo ingressar com o chamado, mas não achei nenhum usuário com o seu nome em nosso sistema.

Comment: Bem Paulo, eu fiz o mesmo teste no Ev1 u5, Ev2 u3, e o problema não acontece, somente na versão do Ev3 que estou usando: Ev3 u11.

Comment: Entendi. Quando a sua gerência abrir o incidente, peça que enviem junto todos estes dados e o Xpz do teste que você fez. Pois eu tenho resultados diferentes dos seus. Continuaremos pó IT